# $|\partial $ as Fourier multiplier

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I have the following nonlinear  dispersive PDEs

$$i \partial_t u- \partial_x^2 u =|\partial_x| |u|^2$$
where $f$ is some nice complex-valued function.

I am trying to use the ansatz  $u(t,x) = e^{i \omega t}\varphi(x)$ to analyze the standing waves. However, I doubt that my calculations to the nonlinear term

\begin{align*}
|\partial_x| |u|^2&=|\partial_x| \varphi^2\\
&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi| \hat{\varphi^2})\\
&= \mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|) * \varphi^2\\
\end{align*}

But I know that there is no point go the last part of the equation. Could you enlighten me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the absolute value $|\partial_x|$ of a differential mean?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, perhaps it is meant as a pseudodifferential operator. What I don't understand is where the function $f$ appears.

Comment: Do you mean "$\lvert\partial\rvert$" (rather than just "$\lvert\partial$") in the title?

Comment: You can write $|\partial||u|^2=R\partial(u\overline{u})=2R\Re(\overline{u}\partial u)$, where $R$ is the Riesz transform. After this point, it depends on where you want to go

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona I want to analyse the traveling wave solution of the ODE that will result from substituting the ansatz above. However, I do not know how to put the nonlinear term in terms of $varphi$